# Angular Firestore - How to handle errors retrieving data

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, error-handling, google-cloud-firestore

I've used firestore in various components to output data from collections and documents with both `snapshotChanges(`) and `subscribe()` methods, but this pretty much relies on data being present, and doesn't look to handle any errors, for example when data is not found or there is an error retrieving it.

I've looked at the documentation, but it's not very clear at all how errors are supposed to be handled when getting data.

How can I catch any errors and log them for firestore-based methods in components like this:?

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { InvoiceService } from '../invoice.service';

import { Invoice } from '../invoiceModel';
import { InvoiceItem } from '../invoiceItemModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-invoice',
  templateUrl: './view-invoice.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-invoice.component.scss']
})

export class ViewInvoiceComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  userId: string;

  invoiceId: string;
  invoice: Invoice;

  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<InvoiceItem>;
  items: Observable<InvoiceItem[]>;
  itemsData = new MatTableDataSource<InvoiceItem>();

  tableColumns = [
    'description',
    'quantity',
    'unitPrice',
    'subtotal',
    'taxCode',
    'tax',
    'total'
  ]

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private invoiceService: InvoiceService, private db: AngularFirestore, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.userId = this.authService.user.uid;

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.invoiceId = params.id;
    })

    this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).ref.get().then(snapshot => {
        this.invoice = snapshot.data() as Invoice;
    })      

    this.itemsCollection = this.db.collection('/users').doc(this.userId).collection('/invoices').doc(this.invoiceId).collection('/items');

    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as InvoiceItem;
            data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return data;
        })
    })

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getItems().subscribe(data => {
        this.itemsData.data = data
    })
    this.itemsData.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.itemsData.sort = this.sort;
  }

  getItems() {
    return this.items
  }

}
```